# .NET Web API MessageHandler Timing Out

Tags: c#, .net, authentication, asp.net-web-api

This question arose when working with the [Thinktecture.IdentityModel.40 library](https://github.com/thinktecture/Thinktecture.IdentityModel.40) (which is used for authentication in .NET's Web API), however it seems to apply more generally to MessageHandlers / DelegateHandlers. The SendAsync(..) function of the AuthenticationHandler class modifies the Web API's response using a ContinueWith(..) call:

```
return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken).ContinueWith(
    (task) => {
        var response = task.Result;

        if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized) {
            SetAuthenticateHeader(response);
        }

        return response;
    }
);
```

[REFERENCE](https://github.com/thinktecture/Thinktecture.IdentityModel.40/blob/master/IdentityModel/Thinktecture.IdentityModel/Tokens/Http/AuthenticationHandler.cs)

The first request to the Web API works fine. All subsequent requests timeout. Using Fiddler, absolutely no response is received for anything after the first request. I thought it may be a caching issue, so I tacked on a couple headers:

```
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: -1
```

But these had no effect. If I update the code to:

```
return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken).ContinueWith(
    (task) => {
        ..
    }
    , TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously
);
```

Then the issue is resolved.

I've read that the order that configurations are applied in the Global.asax can affect MessageHandlers. I've tried rearranging these, but this did not seem to have any affect:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Services.Replace(typeof(IHttpControllerSelector), new AreaHttpControllerSelector(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration));

XmlConfigurator.Configure();//Applies Log4Net configuration
AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

AuthenticationConfig.ConfigureGlobal(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);//Applies Thinktecture's AuthenticationHandler
FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

Bootstrapper.Initialise();//Applies dependency injection
```

At the moment I have a solution, but it is unsatisfying because I do not understand the cause of the issue. Am I missing something obvious?

Thanks.

Comment: Currently I am dealing with something similar I am also using the thinkindentity model as to enable CORS. Using a client like fiddler I make 10 or so requests just fine then after a while it will start to timeout and return null objects. After your first requests does it respond at all or do you just have to kill it off ? Also for some reason each request I make sends two OPTIONS requests, and two POSTS I'm thinking mine is a configuration issue.